# API rest Как передать параметры запроса в URL

Tags: python, api, url

Хочу передать в URL параметры для дальнейшей работы с ними.
как я могу это зделать?

```
http://example.com/sys?login=nix&psw=123&phones=090909&mes=one
login=nix
psw=123
phones=090909
mes=one
```

Comment: Ну вот у вас уже готовая ссылка с параметрами, в чём проблема?

Comment: Как мне их обработать в python, или передать в aws lambda.
Нужен api который будет обрабатывать эти данные.
Что бы я мог работать с полученными данными.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074803/retrieving-parameters-from-a-url